# Eval() and Function() under LockerService

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I started working to make some of my lightning components compliant with `LockerService` announced recently by Salesforce.

One of my Lightning Components (already in production for some orgs) rely on the use of `eval()` and `new Function()`. I use them to interpret a string expression. So basically I'm evaluating expression like: `eval("'something' == 'something else'");` and I expect to receive `false`.

When I'm running analysis tool I'm getting following errors:

```
no-new-func       The Function constructor is eval    
no-eval           eval can be harmful
```

And here is the question. Would there be any way to get around it without writting whole expression evaluator? Or it means that starting Winter 17' - these components will stop working?

Answer (score 3):

(changed) All forms of unsafe-eval, including setTimeout(string), are not allowed by our security requirements, but beginning with Summer ’18, we provide a safe version of eval() and Function(). See the [Summer ’18 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_locker_service.htm)

(changed) All form of unsafe-inline are blocked by content security policy (CSP) which is by default. If you have an older org, we recommend turning the preference "Stricter CSP" on. See the [Critical Update for Stricter CSP Restrictions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_csp_stricter.htm).

Where are the dynamic parts of your expressions coming from? What are the operators and functions you need to support? I am thinking out loud here but it's very possible you could just leverage Lightning's built in expression engine that is already LS compliant.

Comment: When you mean unsafe eval() - is there any way to do save eval()?
In most cases it's purely string eval. Component logic is building string to be evaluated. Most common scenarios are: 'string' == 'other string' or if (condition) { 'something'} else { 'sth else' }

Comment: Regarding expressions - my understanding is that expressions can be used only in .cmp and .app files - within {! ... } tags. I'm looking for a solution to evaluate expression within controller.js or helper.js files.

Comment: All forms of eval() are not allowed in LC - this and unsafe-inline's are the basis for all XSS attacks that we need to eliminate. The term "unsafe-eval" comes from Content Security Policy and is a bit misleading since I see how it implies that there might be a safe alternative. Expressions can be created dynamically but might not be the best routwe if you need that much expressiveness. An alternative would be to leverage a small, hidden VF page via an iframe and postMessage(). This is similar to what Lightning framework does itself for the same reasons.

Answer (score 1):

As of Summer '18, LC allows safe eval() and safe Function() due to popular demand.

See the release notes here:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_locker_service.htm