# Use Apex Functions in String format within Apex code

Tags: apex

I have text box to input apex function names. For example text box may have `DateTime.Today()`. I want to read this Text box String value in apex code and use as the standard function. Is there any way we can do that? The issue is the value comes as a String and cannot use it.

Comment: Can't evaluate a String at runtime into Apex.

Comment: I don't see why this has 3 close votes of "off-topic".

Comment: my guess is ppl thought that the post was missing a code sample to better understand what the OP was attempting to do.

Comment: I voted to close, since there's a specific issue thats missing, and that's what the op is trying to do that led them to this point. I think other solutions could be considered other than apex, which due to the scope of the question being very apex focused, aren't being considered.

Comment: Fair comments on why close votes might be made; pity not every close vote was accompanied by a comment (or vote on a comment) so the OP could understand what the issue was.

Answer (score 6):

There is no (simple) mechanism to run arbitrary Apex code and if there was it would represent a serious security problem as code such as `delete [select Id from Account];` could be executed.

(JavaScript has an `eval` function that allows arbitrary JavaScript code to be executed so that has to be blocked to make Lightning Components secure - see [Eval() and Function() under LockerService](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126841/eval-and-function-under-lockerservice).)

If you have a distinct set of operations you can offer those as a picklist and execute locked down code for each one. Beyond that, it is possible to write an expression parser and create your own (safe) mini-language but that is a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks Keith. Yeah I understand  issues behind this. However i tried this in executeAnonymous as sfdxfox pointed out. However it doesn't work on asynchronous context

Answer (score 5):

The closest that you can get to today is to call "execute anonymous", which requires administrative privileges to avoid security problems.

You would call it like this:

```
req.setEndpoint('http://***instance***.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/'+
    'tooling/executeAnonymous/?anonymousBody='+
    EncodingUtil.urlEncode(sourceCode,'utf-8'));
req.setMethod('GET');
```

There is no concept of "reflection" in the world of Apex Code, so it's not trivially possible to execute random code on the fly.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I tried this. However this doesn't work on an Asynchronous context though. I want to run that on both synchronous and asynchronous context. Any lead??

Comment: @LMudiyanse Basically, you can't, again, because language reflection doesn't exist. Keith's idea, allowing execution from a predefined set of blocks, might be doable, but you're definitely not going to be able to execute arbitrary code in any context.